# Import gtk working in shell but not in scripts (windows)

Tags: python, linux, windows

If I run:

**`ti.py`** (only part of code)

```
import pygtk
import gtk
```

I get:

```
File ti.py.line 2 , in (module)
import gtk
File"C:\python27\lib\site-packages/gtk-2.0\gtk\__init__.py",line 40 in (module)


from gtk import _gtk
ImporError : DLL Load Failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

But if I run it inside shell it works perfectly.

The Python script gives the `ImportError`, whilst in the shell it imported perfectly.

I have installed `pygtk 2.24` from the all in one installer.

What is the cause?

Comment: Do you have `gtk` installed on Windows?

Comment: I'd post the actual code, too (at least the section with the import).